# Huge delay before RPC call

Tags: performance, web-services, gwt, playframework, rpc

I'm currently programming a web application implying a Web server (Play! framework) and a GWT UI. It's a single page application : some widgets are showed or hidden during its execution.

In this application, I want to call an aynchronous service using a RPC call. It has got a very simple parameter (a Long), although its return's type is way more complex. 
The problem i'm encountering is that there's a long delay between the RPC call and the real service execution (it can be from 3 seconds to 18 seconds, 5 seconds on average). This delay occurs in production mode (of course in development mode also)

Client side :

```
  // print current time
  coolServices.doSomething(id, new AsyncCallback<ComplexType>() {

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
    // error
  }

  @Override
  public void onSuccess(ComplexType result) {
    //success
    }
  }
});
```

Server side :

```
@Override
  public ComplexType doSomething(Long id) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            // print current time
            // do something...
    return response;
```

}

Have you an idea of solution to this problem ? 
By the way, I believe the events queue is empty at the service call...

Thanks in advance, 
xela85

Comment: It's not clear from your question where this delay occurs. Is it between the time you call this service and the server receives the call (unlikely), or the server starts to return the response, or the client gets a complete response?

Comment: It's between the time I call this service and the server receives the call

Comment: I use similar code in hundreds of RPC calls, and I never saw a delay like that. Something else must be happening in your code. How complex is your ComplexType?

Comment: I have the same problem. Any solutions so far?